# Optimize a necessary while loop with insert statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, sql-insert

I have a series of procedures that run a bit of math in a while loop.  They are calculating running averages in which knowing the previously calculated values is absolutely necessary in order to get the next value.  An item is paired with an array of values, sequenced by date, and are using 10 distinct methods to calculate the running average.

To answer some questions in advance: The array length will be identical per id for each run, but there can be null values if data is missing.  I do not know in advance the number of ids for which rolling averages are being calculated and it will be different every time.  I do not know in advance the number of necessary iterations and it will be different every time.  I have not discovered a mathematical way to flatten the system into one select/join, despite working on the calculus for over a year - 5 are non-linear and I only had 4 semesters of calculus in college, so it's beyond my understanding to figure out a flattened solution (I did for 5 of the 10 methods I'm working, but the remaining 5 are either too complicated or require before-hand knowledge of the sequence in which the values arrive - which will be different every time they're run).

My code runs, and the 5 methods that use the while loops do finish, but it takes about 15min-30min to run 5000 items (all with their own iterations and calculations) per method.  I need to be able to scale up to 300000 items, so 15min is not tenable, especially since this is one of dozens of procedures running in the DB.

An example of my code for one of the methods is below.  I'm not looking for help in the math part (since the math is different for each of the 5 procs that require loops), but in the insert statement that's used as the intention behind the loop:

```
create proc analysis.calculateavg_logarithmicshifted
    @maxi int --max number of iterations determined by separate proc
as
    
declare @icount int = 1;
declare @n int;
select @n = max(n) from #temp_pink; --comes from the procedure that calls this one, and is a way to identify the max array size
    
drop table if exists analysis.avglogarithmicshifted;
    
create table analysis.avglogarithmicshifted(    
    id nvarchar(64),    
    i int,  
    mu decimal(19, 6),  
    insertdate datetime,    
    avgname nvarchar(64)    
);
    
drop table if exists #temp_k;

--Pull only the historic data from the source
select  
    id, 
    k,  
    price
into #temp_k
from #temp_bbfull --original list of data, n elements per id
where history = 1;
    
while @icount <= @maxi  
    begin;      

    drop table if exists #temp_premu;
    
    --Calculate one sub-section of the rolling average
    select          
        id,         
        sum(log(price)) / (@n - sum(case when price is null then 1 else 0 end)) as premu        
    into #temp_premu        
    from #temp_k        
    where k between @icount and @icount + @n
    group by id;        
    
    drop table if exists #temp_f;           
    
    --Calculate the main component of the rolling average
    select          
        k.id,           
        @icount + @n as k,          
        exp(p.premu + (sum(power(log(k.price) - p.premu, 2)) / (2 * (@n - sum(case when k.price is null then 1 else 0 end))))) as price     
    into #temp_f        
    from #temp_k k          
    join #temp_premu p              
        on p.id= k.id           
    join #temp_bbfull bb                
        on bb.id= k.id              
        and bb.k = k.k      
    where k.k between @icount 
        and @icount + @n
    group by k.id, p.premu;         
    
    --Insert this iteration's rolling average into the table with incremented identifier k
    insert into #temp_k (id, k, price)      
    select          
        *       
    from #temp_f        
    where price is not null;        
    
    select @icount = @icount + 1;   
end;

--Insert final aggregated data into destination table
insert into analysis.avglogarithmicshifted (id, i, mu, insertdate, avgname)
select  
    k.id,   
    k.k - @n as I,  
    k.price as mu,  
    getdate() as insertdate,    
    'Logarithmic Shifted' as avgname
from #temp_k k
where k.k > @n  
    and k.price is not null;
```

Names and identifiers have been changed from my original code, but nothing else has.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using SQL Server 17.9.1

Comment: I would honestly ask *is* the `WHILE` **really** necessary? There are very few times you need a `WHILE` in SQL; *very* few. I doubt you really need one.

Comment: *"I'm using SQL Server 17.9.1"* There's no such thing; the latest version of SQL Server is 15.0.4083.2 (which is SQL Server 2019 RTM-CU8-GDR).

Comment: We have optimize this calculus by using a SQL-CLR agregating function instead of the SUM(LOG...

Comment: The loop is necessary due to the math (x_2 requires knowledge of x_1, and x_3 requires knowledge of x_2 and x_1, etc), but it doesn't have to be a while loop if there's a better option.

Comment: I misread the version number - what I wrote was the SSMS software version number.  I'm using 14.0.17289 or something of the sort

Comment: Do the temp tables have any indexes?  The appropriate indexes could help.  Look at the execution plan for missing indexes or inappropriate scans.  I wouldn't drop and recreate a table in a proc; create it once and only truncate it within your proc.  Potentially the temp tables could be converted to in-memory OLTP tables which could be faster.  From experience, the secret to making things like this go faster, is a working reproduction (or "repro") of the problem.  The full schema, representative sample data and a way of running and re-running over and over again.  Invest some time in that.

Comment: I re-ran the proc (with an identical dataset) using truncate/insert statements on tables I generated with indexes, but it **added** a significant amount of time to the processing (+20%).

Comment: So was it only the TRUNCATE change you made?  What indexes did you add?  I'm working in the dark here.  The (continued) trick to solving these is finding the most expensive statements.  Fire up Profiler.  Use the template TSQL_SPs  and add a filter for the SPID your are running your proc in.  This will tell you which statements are taking the longest but also add an overhead.  find the statement that is taking the longest and tune it.  Because you're in a loop this will have a multiplier positive effect.

Comment: What sort of volumes (numbers of records) are you working with?  What kind of values go in each column?  What range of values gets passed in as a parameter?  1-100, 1-1,000,000 ?

Comment: I changed the drop to truncate, and the #temp tables to indexed tables, changing to the proper insert as well.

The number of simultaneously processed records (```ID```) range from the low hundreds to the low hundred-thousands.  

```Price``` is decimal (19, 2) and greater than 0.  Iterations are never greater than 300 or less than 8. Usually it's between 45-175 (```maxi``` is the max of that). ```ID``` is nvarchar(64), but rarely needs that many characters, usually closer to 16 - but there are circumstances where it gets that high.  ```k``` is int and maxes at 90 + iterations.

Comment: Do you need the third table (temp_bbfull) in the big query?  Being as temp_k is populated from that, and  temp_premu from there.  The one potential issue I can see is the history = 1 filter in the initial population.  Removing this third join sped up the big query significantly in my simple [test rig](https://gist.github.com/wBobuk/810541bb66a194ad0183db65cd32ff0b).

Comment: The #temp_bbfull is only the foundational data, and from it the first rolling average per ID is calculated. That value is needed for the next one and so on (they overlap, hence the insert - and being unable to window past the first iteration). I'm using rolling averages here to approx. a forecast to determine per ID which method (of the 10) is closest to recent historical data from older historical data.The ```history = 1``` filters out the recent data, and shrinks the dataset by about 30-40%. I could try running smaller groups of IDs, but the total number of IDs will remain unchanged.

Comment: Hi, not sure if my point was clear - in the query with the three temp tables, can you remove the third temp table?  In my test rig, it does not change the result, because all data in the other two tables ultimately comes from that table, so in theory a join would not  add an additional filter, and no columns in the INSERT statement come from that third table.  Have a look at my test rig and see if we can make it more authentic.

Answer (score 0):

Overall I do not think you will be able to gain anywhere near 100x (2 orders of magnitude) improvement that you are looking for without major redesign of your code. I do not understand the logic of your code so cannot help, other than to say that SQL Server 2016 supports window functions that do allow set based computation of moving averages. This link may be of [help](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calculate-moving-averages-using-t-sql-in-sql-server)

Below are some tips to optimise it:

- When joining many temp tables ensure that tables with a lot of data
  have indexes.
- Try to reduce the number of temp tables used to store intermediate calculation results.
- Ensure that the number of rows in intermediate temp tables is as few as possible.

From the example you have given I can see some **possible** optimisations. As I do not have the data I cannot check if they will help or not:

0 `#temp_bbfull` - looks like this table is used as a data source and has a lot of data. You **must** have correct indexes on it.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_temp_bbfull ON #temp_bbfull( id, k )
```

1 Restrict your working set as much as possible

```
select  id, k, price
into #temp_k
from #temp_bbfull --original list of data, n elements per id
-- As you are restricting iterations you might as well restrict the number of rows upfront
where history = 1 and k between @icount and @maxi;
```

2 This may or may not help.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_temp_k ON temp_k( id )
```

3 Combine queries

```
select          
    k.id, @icount + @n as k,          
    exp(p.premu + (sum(power(log(k.price) - p.premu, 2)) / (2 * (@n - sum(case when k.price is null then 1 else 0 end))))) as price     
into #temp_f        
from #temp_k as k          
    join (
         select id, sum(log(price)) / (@n - sum(case when price is null then 1 else 0 end)) as premu        
         from #temp_k        
         where k between @icount and @icount + @n
         group by id ) as p
     on p.id= k.id
    join #temp_bbfull as bb on bb.id= k.id and bb.k = k.k      
where k.k between @icount and @icount + @n
group by k.id, p.premu;
```

and so on.

Comment: I could shrink the size of the sets I work with, but cannot shrink the total number of IDs I need to run weekly (it will only ever grow).  Combining the queries could help, but maybe only in the method I used as an example as the other 4 have different mathematical structures. The query plan and analysis shows the insert being the killer in terms of process time and usage. I'll try the indexing method to see if that helps, though from all this I think my best hope lies in a mathematician solving my non-linear flattening problem.

Comment: Insert is typically the fastest operation in SQL Server. Are you sure that the insert is the problem and not the selects that produce the results? If inserts are indeed a problem check that your tempDB is correctly setup (there are numerous articles on how to set it up for best performance)

Comment: Look into window functions. I think your logic (at least some of it) can be migrated to use them: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/introduction-to-t-sql-window-functions/

Comment: I'm very familiar with window functions, but since I'm not calculating a rolling avg over an existing set of data, but instead using a rolling avg over data I'm creating as it's rolling - I'm pretty sure the rows preceding/between (and lead/lag etc) won't work.  I considered doing a windowed recursion, but since I don't know the ultimate number of iterations before I start, and maxrecursion doesn't allow for variables, I thought it could cause some major internal conflicts but it's worth testing.

Comment: So it turns out aggregate functions are not allowed in recursions, so I can't see a way to make windows work since any iterations after the first depends on the previous values having already been calculated.